# Authenticate session when calling api routes from ajax in frontend

Tags: ajax, laravel, api, authentication, session

I have a Laravel project where I use the same controllers for web- and api- routes by checking the `request->wantsJson()` to determine what to return. I'm using the built in `Auth` for web routes.

In the front end, I use `jQuery/ajax` to fetch and post data, but I'm not sure how to forward the current logged in user in the ajax-calls so the requests can both be authenticated and the current user be identified.

What I would like to do is to attach some kind of temporary `session` token in the request header when doing the `ajax` calls and authenticate this as a user through `middleware`.

What is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: If you're using the same Web routes for both calls, you don't need to send the token. `Auth::user()` should be able to detect if you're logged whether or not it is an `ajax` for regular request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip Tim, but as I'm planning on accessing the api for external clients as well, I figured I needed some token middleware.

I solved it using `tymon/jwt-auth` on all api routes and adding to my user class

> public function getToken(){
>       return JWTAuth::fromUser($this); 
>   }

Then i simply add this to the header in ajax calls

> headers: {
>
> 'Authorization': `Bearer {{auth()->user()->getToken()}}`,
>    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>    'Accept': 'application/json'
>   },